# useState with a boolean

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

i have a react next.js project and a form. i want to use a slider in my form. by the way i use semantic ui react. i have one useState hook with the following input:

```
function CreateTicket() {
  const [ticket, setTicket] = useState({
    name: "",
    description: "",
    media: "",
    priority: false
  });
....
```

and an handleChange, handleSubmit and an handleToggle function. When i submit the form in my console.log it dont set the value of priority back to false.

```
      <Checkbox
        style={{ padding: "1rem" }}
        label="Important?"
        name="priority"
        toggle
        onChange={handleToggle}
      />

  const handleToggle = event => {
    let { priority } = event.target;
    setTicket(prevState => ({ ...prevState, priority: !priority }));
  };
```

console.log ->

after page refresh:

```
{name: "", description: "", media: "", priority: false}
```

after: toggle

```
{name: "", description: "", media: "", priority: true}
```

after a second toggle

```
{name: "", description: "", media: "", priority: true}
```

What do i wrong?

Comment: `event.target` does not have a property `priority` as far as I can tell, and `!undefined` is `true`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to destructure `priority` from `prevState`, not `event.target`:

```
const handleToggle = event => {
  setTicket(({ priority, ...prevState }) =>
    ({ ...prevState, priority: !priority })
  );
};
```

As an optimization, you can memoize `handleToggle` with `useCallback()` so that `<Checkbox/>` doesn't need to re-render every time your state updates:

```
const handleToggle = useCallback(event => {
  setTicket(({ priority, ...prevState }) =>
    ({ ...prevState, priority: !priority })
  );
}, [setTicket]);
```